# Rose's and spider plants

Tags: roses

My husband planted his spider plant in my rose garden as ground covering. It is now growing up and into my rose bushes. It is taking over my rose garden! Will it kill my Rose's? How do I get it out?
Tracey Huffman

Comment: If you live anywhere that gets below freezing during the winter, the spider plants will die. Where in the world are you located?

Comment: Riverside, CA and it usually gets very hot here. I just don't like the idea that the baby "spiders" are growing up and into my rose bushes. It looks like one big blob of green and not individual bushes.